# Borders arround words

Tags: graphics

I dont know even where to start.
Anyone knows how to get this in Latex ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to tex ! have a look on https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx And give us a MWE

Comment: see the package `tcolorbox`.